# Bad Request Error on surveymonkey V3 send

Tags: httr, surveymonkey

I'm trying to send a message from the v3 SurveyMonkey api.  In doing so, I'm using the following pattern as required from the API:

```
POST /surveys/{id}/collectors
POST /collectors/{id}/messages
POST /collectors/{id}/messages/{id}/recipients/bulk
POST /collectors/{id}/messages/{id}/send
```

Steps 1-3 work fine, but when I try to issue the send command, I get a 400 Bad Request error.  The error message states:

```
"The body provided was not a proper JSON string."
```

I am using the httr package in R to send the message if that helps.

```
  u <- paste('https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors', collectorID, "messages", messageID, "send", sep="/")
  h <- httr::add_headers(Authorization = token) 

  out <- httr::POST(u, config = h)
```

As I review the API documentation, it does not appear that a body is required for this command.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For step 4:

```
POST /collectors/{id}/messages/{id}/send
```

A body is actually required. There is an optional field (`scheduled_date`). If you want it to send right away without scheduling, you send an empty JSON object.

```
'{}'
```

And that'll work, but it still expects a JSON body.